# Sum rows if header and first column meet criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, pivot, flatten, google-query-language

I have a table with first row as header and first column as week number, I need to sum all the data on every week that meets the criteria depending on the header name.

This formula only filter by header and week, but I can't summarize the data, I would like that the formula is "dynamic" because the header name section can change:

> =QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:AA23),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 = 'M.O.'",1)

This is an example spreadsheet, at the end is the desired result:
[LINK TO EXAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o7sgej-I1iIK_rI5cvy4OLFojv0hBLC02cMiWRJfS3I/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(D2:24="",,D1:1&"×"&A2:A24&"×"&D2:24)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 matches 'INDIRECTO|M.O.' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"))
```

[image]